# Creating and linking dynamic elements simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm creating two elements: foo and bar and I need these linked at the same time.

```
<div class="target-1"></div>
<div class="target-2"></div>
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

These are the targets for the created elements. Now here's the js:

```
var index = 0;
$("form").submit(function(){
  $(".target-1").append(
    $("<span/>", {class: "foo", id: "s-" + index++}));
  $(".target-2").append(
    $("<span/>", {class: "bar s-" + index}));
});
```

Now this is meant to create a span.foo inside target-1 with the id "s-n" and at the same time create another span.bar inside target-2 with the class "s-n" that is the exact same as the id of the span.foo.

What it actually does is create span.foo id="s-0" and span.bar class="s-1". I don't understand why since I'm increasing index in the first append and then setting the current state of index in the second append.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Yrrfd/ but I just use the button and no form since you can't submit forms in jsfiddle. But it should be working the same and you can see the different index values regardless.

Comment: Why don't you just increment `index` before both appends, in much more readable.

Comment: Yeah that's what everyone suggested and what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing the index after the assignment you need to use `++index` instead of `index++`

```
$(".target-1").append(
    $("<span/>", {class: "foo", id: "s-" + ++index})); // Here
  $(".target-2").append(
    $("<span/>", {class: "bar s-" + index}))
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFGdh/)

Post-Increment operator will assign first and then increment. You need pre-increment operator.

Comment: You again. I should just start sending you all my work. Once again, I must thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `++index` instead of `index++`.

`index++` gives you the value and then increments it. `++index` increments it and then gives you the value.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `++index` so that the index is incremented and then used. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrrfd/5/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your requirement 100%, but I think you need to change it to

```
var index = 0;
$("form").submit(function(){
  $(".target-1").append(
    $("<span/>", {class: "foo", id: "s-" + index}));
  $(".target-2").append(
    $("<span/>", {class: "bar s-" + index}));
  index++;
});
```

Or

```
var index = 0;
    $("form").submit(function(){
      index++;
      $(".target-1").append(
        $("<span/>", {class: "foo", id: "s-" + index}));
      $(".target-2").append(
        $("<span/>", {class: "bar s-" + index}));
    });
```

Comment: Close. Like everyone said, I need the ++index and not just index since it will be used over and over so the values need to increase.

Comment: @o_O: you can increase it before creating spans, or increase it after creating spans (the next time you call it, the index was increased). Check my updated answer. I think the code is easier to understand

Comment: @o_O: since we're working in a team. Simple code is preferred because everyone is easy to understand and maintain it

Answer (score 0):

at very first time the index value is (0) and index++ ( first use then increment) so it will use as 0 then incremented by 1 and continue for bar, which is now 1.

```
var index = 0;
$("form").submit(function(){
  $(".target-1").append(
    $("<span/>", {class: "foo", id: "s-" + index}));
  $(".target-2").append(
    $("<span/>", {class: "bar s-" + index++}));
});
```

So you need to increment your index variable at bar append function.